# TortoiseSVN through a proxy script

Tags: svn, proxy, tortoisesvn

I'm attempting to connect to a remote HTTPS SVN server from inside a corporate firewall using TortoiseSVN. I am required to use a proxy for this connection. My problem is that TortoiseSVN's proxy settings only include an option to set a direct proxy server address. The proxy I am connecting through, however, is configured via a script. In Firefox, for example, I use the "Automatic proxy configuration URL" option in the network settings.

Is there any way to use a proxy configuration scripts with Tortoise? I can't find one in the config UI - is there a way to configure it through editing a config file?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There may be a cleaner way to do this but you could simply get the URL of the automatic configuration file from your firefox settings and open it: .pac files are raw text with a fairly simple syntax.

Extracting the ip/port and other configuration info for your corporate proxy from that file should be relatively simple (look for the one  that applies to your IP range if there are more than one).

Obviously, this isn't very pretty in the sense that, if the proxy configuration changes, you'll have to do this again instead of benefiting from the automated settings. In practice, this simple trick has been very useful for everything from Putty to TortoiseSVN for me !

Comment: It worked perfectly, thanks. I just entered the URL from the script into Firefox and it let me download the script file. The script ended up being unexpectedly complex, but I was able to run it through the pacparser library at http://code.google.com/p/pacparser, which was able to immediately tell me which proxy to use for the SVN url. Waiting for the current revision to finish downloading as I type this :)

Comment: Glad I could help, and thanks for the link to pacparser ! It might come in hand if our IT decides to make the pac file more complex, ours is pretty long but simple enough to parse manually.

Comment: What if there are SVN repositories inside AND outside of the LAN? Is it necessary for me to keep turning on and off the "Enable Proxy Server" option in the settings? --- If the tool is a thingy which integrates into the Windows File Explorer then it is not too far to create a "Use Internet Explorer settings".

Comment: +1 - this just helped me out massively for getting Moq via TortoiseSVN, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK TortoiseSVN and Subversion in general lacks direct support for proxy configuration scripts (aka *.pac files).

As mentioned in the accepted answer, you can download the proxy config script, extract the matching rule from the configuration and set it as proxy, but this workaround has two drawbacks:

1. Whenever your sysadmins change the config script, you will run into connectivity problems, which will take time to diagnose, then you'll have to take another look at the configuration script, change your settings, etc.
2. If the SVN servers used fall under multiple proxy configuration rules resulting in multiple proxy servers used, you will have to change your TSVN proxy settings whenever you want to connect to another SVN server.

Now the former problem (maintenance) is beyond what I could solve, but the latter (sophisticated proxy config), may be tackled using Subversion's **servers** configuration file, which is itself a kind of proxy configuration file. The file can be reached via context menu / TortoiseSVN / Settings / Network tab / Subversion server file / Edit button.

The default servers file is pretty well commented, including some examples. Two important features to look for are **groups** and the **http-proxy-exceptions** setting. Using the servers file you will be able to set up simple proxy rules based on the original proxy configuration script.

[The official Subversion FAQ also mentions the servers file.](https://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#proxy)