# How to access the internet through a proxy configuration script?

Tags: python, ruby, proxy

I want to install some ruby gems and some python libraries ( preferably using `easy_install` ) on some computers. It's an easy enough job, but the thing is, I need to use a proxy to do so. I know how to install using a proxy, but, for example, to surf the web, these computers are using a proxy configuration script, which points to .pac file.

Can I make the tools connect to the internet using this pac file?

Comment: Many programs respect `http_proxy` environment variable, perhaps these tools do too. Try: `http_proxy=http://proxy.hostname:3128/ gem install ...`

Comment: Sure but, I don't have a `proxy` per se, that configuration script will choose one after it runs.

Comment: ohhhh. Does the `.pac` file have anything that looks like a simple hostname+port combination? Maybe also including a username+password for HTTP Basic or Digest authentication? Or is it much worse than that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TortoiseSVN through a proxy script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222921/tortoisesvn-through-a-proxy-script)